# 文字列の数字への置き換え:文字列に揺らぎがある場合

Tags: python, pandas

[以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47953/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%8D%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%88)の拡張です。

xに入っている路線名を、辞書line_namesにあるような数字に置き換えたいと考えています。
しかし、路線名にはJRや都営などが付いたり、つかなかったりなど揺らぎあることが分かりました。

現在用意したcodeでは、完全に一致するもののみ、置き換えます。

用意した辞書と部分的に一致したものを番号に変換し、一致しないものは、欠損値にしたいのですが、
ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['ＪＲ山手線',
           '山手線',
           'ＪＲ総武線',
           '総武線',
           '西武池袋線',
           '都営大江戸線',
          　'大江戸線',
           'ＪＲ中央線',
           '中央線',
           'バス',
           '車']})

line_names = {"山手線":"1",
        "総武線":"2",
        "西武池袋線":"3",
        "都営大江戸線":"4",
        "中央線":"5"}

#get() を使うとデフォルト値を指定できます。
df['y'] = df.apply(lambda row: line_names.get(row["x"], np.NaN), axis=1)
```

Comment: lambdaで書かれている部分をもうちょっと柔軟な関数に置き換えるとか。例えば、正規表現を使ったマッチにすれば完全一致以外にも対応できますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今後の課題とします！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関数を作ってこんな感じで書けます。

```
def get_line(x):
    for l in line_names:
        if l in x :
          return line_names[l]
    return np.NaN

df['y'] = df['x'].map(get_line)
```

実際の問題では、`df`に大量のデータがあるので、先に`df['x'].unique()`で`df`内にある路線名を全て抽出して、それの番号を計算して辞書を作っておくと処理が速くなります。

Comment: 関数を示唆して頂きましたこと、お礼申し上げます。.unique()を知りませんでしたので、大変助かります。